# Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined --- navigator.serviceWorker.register('worker.js')

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get a javascript to work, however. It is giving me some issues.
The demo of the working script from the author is here.
https://toohotradio.net/metadata/
I am using the same code he has on his demo page.

I downloaded the worker.js and have it stored in my JS folder.
So it looks like this in the code.

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {  var iceworker = navigator.serviceWorker.register('worker.js')
//I get this error in Google Chrome
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined
//For this line.
navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('message', event => {
```

Here is the script from the link above.

```
<audio preload="none" id="aud" controls src="https://toohotradio.net/metadata/icy/" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
<div></div>
<ul>
</ul>
<script>
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  var iceworker = navigator.serviceWorker.register('metadataworker.js')
    .then(function(reg) {
      console.log('Icecast service worker registered');
      addItem('Icecast service worker registered. Click play to start the stream.');
    }).catch(function(error) {
    console.warn('Error ' + error);
    addItem('Error ' + error);
  });
}
var delay = 8000;
navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('message', event => {
  if(event.origin != 'https://toohotradio.net'){
    return;
  }
  setTimeout(function(){
    document.querySelector('div').innerText = event.data.msg.substring(event.data.msg.indexOf("'") + 1,event.data.msg.lastIndexOf("'"));
  },delay);
  console.log(event.data.msg);
  addItem('Message from service worker ' + event.data.msg);
});
document.querySelector('audio').addEventListener('play', event => {
  performance.mark('play');
  addItem("Measuring buffering time...");
})
  document.querySelector('audio').addEventListener('playing', event => {
  performance.mark('playing');
  performance.measure('delay','play','playing');
  var measures = performance.getEntriesByName("delay");
  delay = measures[0].duration;
  addItem("Buffering took " + (delay/1000).toFixed(2) + " seconds");
  addItem("Setting metadata update delay to " + (delay/1000).toFixed(2) + " seconds");
})
  document.querySelector('audio').addEventListener('pause', event => {
  navigator.serviceWorker.controller.postMessage('message');
  document.querySelector('audio').src = document.querySelector('audio').src;
})
  function addItem(text) {
  var node = document.createElement("li");
  var textnode = document.createTextNode(text);
  node.appendChild(textnode);
  document.querySelector('ul').appendChild(node);
}
</script>
```

I've gone through his code and replaced every section with his domain, to point to mine.
This is the source link for the javascript function.
[Source Code for Javascript](http://view-source:https://toohotradio.net/metadata/metadataworker.js)
Can someone please assist me in getting this working?
Thank you.

Wayne

Comment: Move `navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener` part into `if ('serviceWorker' in navigator)`

Comment: Thanks, ponury. This does run, but does not display the media file information as the official demo does. Only shows. --------------Measuring buffering time... /
Buffering took 6.36 seconds /
Setting metadata update delay to 6.36 seconds

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out.
The URL needs to be **HTTPS** or **localhost**.
Once I did that, it started working.

All is good.

Comment: Thanks mate.  Was driving me dilly

Comment: Glad that I was able to help you out, @fromage9747. I am going to start working on setting up a farm to allow for HTTPS Linux within my network and had forgotten about this thread I started nearly 2 years ago. Glad I had it here, I just need to start implementing it. Hope your project is working well for you.